# Async method in view-model: should this return Task or void?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a view-model which is a UDP network browser for my Android and iOS app (fueled by Xamarin).
UDP is used to broadcast the active instance of the application and to listen to broadcasts in order to discover other app instances on the local (Wifi) network.

My view-model has property

```
public AppInstanceList AppInstances
{
get; set;
}
```

And there is a method

```
public async Task StartDiscoveringAppInstancesAsync()
```

which sets up a while loop which keeps on listening via UPD asynchronously:

```
while(this.networkService != null)
{
    var discoveredInstance = await this.networkService.DiscoverAppInstanceAsync ();
// Omitted: store the discovered instance and add to list of discovered instances.
  this.AppInstances.Add(...);

  // Wait a bit before checking again.
  await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

My problem with this method is the return type of `Task`. Obviously, the method should not be awaited - it is as endless loop and runs until the discovery is stopped.

So should I change it to be `void`? But this would violate async/await principles where `void` should only be used for events.

Whenever I encounter a topic like that I'm wondering if my implementation is actually bad design and there's a different and cleaner approach. Or is the user of the view-model just not supposed to `await` the outcome of the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My problem with this method is the return type of Task. Obviously, the method should not be awaited - it is as endless loop and runs until the discovery is stopped.
>
> So should I change it to be void? But this would violate async/await principles where void should only be used for events.

I would not recommend making this an `async void` method.  You can leave it as `async Task`, and still `await` it.

While the `Task` will never complete, wrapping it within an `await` will still provide benefits, such as automatic exception propagation (in the correct context) if you receive an exception within your never-ending task.  This would also allow you to provide cancellation with proper handling if you chose to do so at some point.

> Whenever I encounter a topic like that I'm wondering if my implementation is actually bad design and there's a different and cleaner approach. Or is the user of the view-model just not supposed to await the outcome of the method?

In this case, I would actually suggest not making this an "async" method in general.  The problem with making it an async method is that an asynchronous method suggests some operation that you're initializing now, but that will complete eventually.  A "never ending" async method is going to be confusing to the user's of this API.

Internally, you may want to keep a method like you have, but expose the API via something like:

```
public void StartAppInstanceDiscoveryService();
public event ExceptionEventHandler DiscoveryErrorReceived; // To propogate back an exception/error case if this fails?
```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. And the StartAppInstanceDiscoveryService() would call the async method and just let it run, keeping a reference to the Task as a member variable?